# Use react ref as selector for jquery

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-ref, jquery-mask

How to use React Ref together with jQuery lib **without specified id** to the input?

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery.mask.js';

class PhoneComponent extends React.Component {
  ref = React.createRef();

  state = {value: ''};

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderMask();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input ref={this.ref} type="text"/>
    )
  }


  renderMask() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    const options = {
      onKeyPress: (cep, e) => this.ref.current.value = cep
    };
    $(***???***).val(value);
    $(***???***).mask('+38(###)###-##-##', options);
  }
```

I would like to share experience as far as i found out it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is so simple but not clear in docs.

The **ref.current** refers to used DOM element and allows to access it for jQuery

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component{
  this.ref = React.createRef();
  ...
  doSomething = () => {
    $(this.ref.current).val(value);
    $(this.ref.current).mask(mask, options);
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually it is documented: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in react docs, titled ["Refs and the DOM"](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
const node = this.myRef.current;
```

> When the ref attribute is used on an HTML element, the ref created in the constructor with React.createRef() receives the underlying DOM element as its current property.

Also, as mentioned in jQuery docs, titled ["How do I select elements when I already have a DOM element?"](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-elements-when-i-already-have-a-dom-element/)

> If you have a variable containing a DOM element, and want to select elements related to that DOM element, simply wrap it in a jQuery object.
>
> ```
> var myDomElement = document.getElementById( "foo" ); // A plain DOM element. 
> $( myDomElement ).find( "a" ); // Finds all anchors inside the DOM element.
> ```

Combining these two descriptions we can say that, to use react ref as a selector for jquery we can simply do:

```
$( this.ref.current ).val(value);
$( this.ref.current ).mask('+38(###)###-##-##', options);
```

where, `this.ref.current` is a plain DOM element.

Comment: gives me undefined $(this.ref.current)

Comment: Make sure you check for undefined and interact with this using a useEffect to prevent trying to access it before it's created.